# How is it so that these character constants have negative values?

Tags: c, character-encoding

Reading K&R 1st paragraph page 44 Chapter 2 - *The definition of C guarantees that any character in the machine's standard printing set will never be negative, so these characters will always be positive quantities in expressions.*

Well enough, but when I run the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", '£');

    return 0;
}
```

I get `-93` as the output. I will just cite some of the negative values I get along with the corresponding characters: `ÿ = -1`, `þ = -2`, `÷ = -9`. I don't understand: if it is true that C guarantees that these values are positive in expressions, how is it that the values are negative?

Comment: [Use `%u` instead of `%d`.](http://codepad.org/ZRTMhG7t)

Comment: @PaulR `%u` is likely to print a large value in this case!

Comment: @IanAbbott: yes, possibly [49827](http://codepad.org/ZRTMhG7t).

Comment: @PaulR Since it is outputting `-93` for `%d`, it will likely output either 65443 (for 16-bit `unsigned int`) or 4294967203 (for 32-bit `unsigned int`).

Comment: Using "%d" in printf requests a signed value. Use "%u".

Comment: @IanAbbott using `%u` istead of `%d` prints the value appropriate for 32-bit `unsigned int`. The reason why I didn't use `%u` is because I doubt that the character set is so big that it would enter the negative part of `int`. Is it? What's going on?

Comment: @ahra You were probably expecting 163 to be printed (if the source file is encoded and compiled as ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 character set). However, `char` appears to be a *signed*, 8-bit, 2's complement integer type on your system, so the range of `char` will be -128 to 127 inclusive.

Comment: To avoid this counter intuitive yet common and conformant behavior, compile with `-funsigned-char`, telling the compiler (gcc and clang) to make `char` unsigned by default.

Comment: That might be a requirement in order to satisfy some concern about transport or storage systems of the day. It's not really relevant today because you don't do mathematical operations on characters, do you? If you used a character code in a lexicographic sort or as an array index in a map, you would cast to an unsigned integer if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K&R is somewhat informal, but apparently “£” is not in your implementation’s “standard printing set.” The C standard is more formal. It specifies that members of the basic execution character set are nonnegative when stored in `char` and defines the set to contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, !, ", #, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, comma, -, period, /, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, [, \, ], ^, _, {, |, }, ~, space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, alert, backspace, carraige return, new line, and a null character. “£” is not among these, so the C standard does not require that its value be nonnegative.

Comment: So technically I should read "standard printing set" in this context as basic ASCII?

Comment: @ahra: K&R is old and not useful as a formal specification for modern C.

Comment: @IanAbbott: There were a variety of machines in use way back when with varied character sets.

Answer (score 1):

The following affect the value of an `int` expressed as a character constant containing a single character:

1. the actual character set and character encoding of the source file;
2. the assumed (by the compiler) character set and character encoding of the source file;
3. whether the character in the character constant is encoded as a multibyte character or a single-byte character;
4. if encoded as a single-byte character, whether the character code falls within the range of the `char` type or not.

Ideally, you want the assumed character set and encoding of the source to match the actual character set and encoding.

The value of a character constant containing a multibyte sequence (more than one byte) is implementation defined.

If the `char` type is signed, there may be single-byte characters in the source that cannot be represented as positive `char` values. Such characters will be represented as negative `char` values.

In OP's example,

```
printf("%d", '£');
```

printed the value -93. Since the '£' character has decimal code 163 in the ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15 character sets, the following seems the most likely deduction:

1. The source character set is actually ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 or possibly some variant such as Windows CP-1252.
2. The source character set assumed by the compiler is ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 or possibly some variant such as Windows CP-1252.
3. Due to 1 and 2 above, all characters in the source are encoded as single bytes.
4. The `char` type on OP's system is an 8-bit, 2's-complement, signed integer type. (N.B. 163 - 256 = -93.)

According to C11 section 6.4.4.4 paragraph 10:

> If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`.

Since `int` can represent all the values of `char` if `char` is signed, and the `int` constant produced by `'£'` was -93 on OP's system, then as long as `'£'` really is a single-byte character constant on OP's system it can be deduced that the `char` value also -93. If `'£'` is actually a multibyte (more than one byte) character constant on OP's system, then its value is implementation defined and no such deduction can be made.

Answer (score 1):

the characters you are concerned about are multi character formats. I.E. 16bits rather than 8 bits I.E. wide characters.  so the statement: `printf("%d", '£');` will cause the compiler to output a warning message.  A much better way to write that statement is: `printf("%d", L'£');`  Notice the 'L' before the character.

When `printf()` prints the value using: `%d` the char is 'promoted` to an integer.

When the upper most bit is 'set', the promotion sees the char as negative so the resulting value will be negative (via sign extension)

However, the upper most bit in this wide character is NOT set, so when the correct data format is used, the `printf()` outputs: `163`