# Alternative to this switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

The code which I posted below is a part of my whole program. The rest of the code is not related to this question. Is there any solution other than using this long `switch` statement? The main objective is to shorten the code. The `if` statement is used simply to capitalize lowercase letters.

```c
int POINTS[] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int compute_score(string word)
{
  // TODO: Compute and return a score for string
  int word_length = strlen(word);
  int i, sum = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < word_length; i++)
  {
    //This if statement is used to captalise lower-case letters.
    if (islower(word[i]))
    {
      word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
    }

    //This switch statement is the key in this program. It will check 
    //each letter of word and then modify variable sum according to it.
    switch (word[i])
    {
    case 'A':
      sum = sum + POINTS[0];
      break;
    case 'B':
      sum = sum + POINTS[1];
      break;
    case 'C':
      sum = sum + POINTS[2];
      break;
    case 'D':
      sum = sum + POINTS[3];
      break;
    case 'E':
      sum = sum + POINTS[4];
      break;
    case 'F':
      sum = sum + POINTS[5];
      break;
    case 'G':
      sum = sum + POINTS[6];
      break;
    case 'H':
      sum = sum + POINTS[7];
      break;
    case 'I':
      sum = sum + POINTS[8];
      break;
    case 'J':
      sum = sum + POINTS[9];
      break;
    case 'K':
      sum = sum + POINTS[10];
      break;
    case 'L':
      sum = sum + POINTS[11];
      break;
    case 'M':
      sum = sum + POINTS[12];
      break;
    case 'N':
      sum = sum + POINTS[13];
      break;
    case 'O':
      sum = sum + POINTS[14];
      break;
    case 'P':
      sum = sum + POINTS[15];
      break;
    case 'Q':
      sum = sum + POINTS[16];
      break;
    case 'R':
      sum = sum + POINTS[17];
      break;
    case 'S':
      sum = sum + POINTS[18];
      break;
    case 'T':
      sum = sum + POINTS[19];
      break;
    case 'U':
      sum = sum + POINTS[20];
      break;
    case 'V':
      sum = sum + POINTS[21];
      break;
    case 'W':
      sum = sum + POINTS[22];
      break;
    case 'X':
      sum = sum + POINTS[23];
      break;
    case 'Y':
      sum = sum + POINTS[24];
      break;
    case 'Z':
      sum = sum + POINTS[25];
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want something like this and simply haven't bothered to set all the indices in your `switch` statement correctly:

```
if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z') {
    sum += POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];
}
```

The trick is that `char`s are just numbers as well, so you can compare them to see if the character is an uppercase Latin letter, and subtract `'A'` to get the 0-based position in the `POINTS` array.

However, note that this only works if the character set on your target system contains the letters `A` through `Z` contiguously in alphabetical order. By far most systems these days use (a superset of) ASCII, where the above code works fine. But if a more exotic character set such as EBCDIC is used, you will need a different approach, such as a lookup table, a hash table, or... a big `switch` statement.

Comment: This does not work in EBCDIC. And, while you might not care about uncommon C implementations, it is not fair to students to teach them false assumptions. Engineers should learn to be aware of requirements, even if adherence to them is common.

Answer (score 3):

A direct and fast alternative is to assign a point value to each `char`.

This also makes for a clear relationship between the letter and value.

```
#include <limits.h>

// Array elements not explicitly initialized are 0.
unsigned char POINTS[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {
    ['A'] = 1, ['a'] = 1, 
    ['B'] = 3, ['b'] = 3, 
    ['C'] = 3, ['c'] = 3,
    /* 23 more pairs */ };  

int compute_score(string word) {
  sum = 0;
  while (*word) {
    sum += POINTS[(unsigned char) *word];
    word++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Or with only using 26 explicit initializers.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned char POINTS[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 3, ['C'] = 3 /* 23 more */ };

int compute_score(string word) {
  sum = 0;
  while (*word) {
    sum += POINTS[toupper((unsigned char) *word)];
    word++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

As `1, 3, 3, ...  8, 4, 10` are apparently [Scrabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble) tile values, consider that code may want to handle other versions of the game that include letters outside A-Z.  With a complete table look-up, only a table data update is needed and not a  functional code one.

Works with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [EBDCIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), ...

Note: On rare machines, the range of `unsigned char` is large (e.g. "byte" size could be 64-bit) rendering this approach impractical.  So maybe add the following for detection.

```
_Static_assert(UCHAR_MAX < 1024, "char size too large");
```

Comment: `char POINTS[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {...};` is going to have problems if any of the actual character values used to initialize the array are negative.  A cast to `unsigned char` might be necessary.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am confident the code's characters must be positive for normal characters - others may need casting. [How is it so that these character constants have negative values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578489/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing that you really want to add e.g. `POINTS[15]` for O, rather than `POINTS[1]` for every letter past E, since your `POINTS` array is 26 elements long. If that's the case, then you can simply do:

```
if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z')
    sum += POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];
```

This will work if your encoding is ASCII (very likely). If it's something else like EBCDIC where the letters aren't consecutive you'll need to use a lookup table.

Comment: Or, to avoid arithmetic with each iteration, declare a static array of size 256 with the points at the specific offset.

Comment: @Cheatah: The size should be `UCHAR_MAX+1`. The C standard permits character types to be wider than eight bits.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the lengthy `switch` statement, there are some issues in your code:

- the `switch` cases for `'F'` and greater seem to use an incorrect offset into the `POINTS` array.
- the function `compute_score()` uppercases its argument string as a side effect. This is not very good practice. Such a side effect would have undefined behavior on a string literal for example.
- If you intend for the string to be uppercased, you should use a function dedicated to that and pass the uppercased string to a simplified version of `compute_score()`. Alternately, you can easily modify `compute_score()` so it does not have a side effect on the argument string.
- You call `strlen()` on the string and run a second loop iterating on all characters in the string. You could simply iterate once, testing if `word[i] == '\0'` to detect the end of string.
- `islower()` and `toupper()` like all functions from `<ctype.h>` are only defined for argument values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. They have undefined behavior for negative `char` values which may occur in the string on platforms where `char` is a signed type. To avoid this undefined behavior, you should cast `char` values as `(unsigned char)`.

Here is a simplified yet portable version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int POINTS[] = { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };

int compute_score(const char *word) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (*word != '\0') {
        int c = toupper((unsigned char)*word++);
        if ('Z' - 'A' == 25) {  /* this test is optimized out at compile time */
            /* simple and efficient code if all uppercase letters are contiguous (ASCII) */
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                sum += POINTS[c - 'A'];
            }
        } else {
            /* portable code for non-ASCII character sets such as EBCDIC */
            static const char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            const char *p = strchr(letters, c);
            if (p != NULL) {
                sum += POINTS[p - letters];
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: *the function `compute_score()` uppercases its argument string as a side effect. This is not very good practice.*  It's a lot worse than "not very good practice".  If the function ever gets passed a string literal it's undefined behavior.  And *Here is a simplified yet portable version*?  Not if the character set isn't ASCII.  You're risking a downvote from someone... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Good point. I amended the answer and improved portability.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `POINTS[1]` is added to `sum` for all upper-case alphabet case other than B, C, D, and E. Therefore, you can combine them.

```
            switch (word[i])
            {
                case 'B':
                    sum = sum + POINTS[2];
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    sum = sum + POINTS[3];
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    sum = sum + POINTS[4];
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    sum = sum + POINTS[5];
                    break;
                default:
                    if (isupper(word[i]))
                    {
                        sum = sum + POINTS[1];
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

If you can assume that the character code for A to Z are continuous (like ASCII and UTF-8, unlike EBCDIC):

```
if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'E') {
    sum = sum + POINTS[(word[i] - 'A') + 1];
} else if ('F' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z') {
    sum = sum + POINTS[1];
}
```

Comment: Note that the result of `isupper` depends on the current locale. A safer check would be something like `word[i] >= 'F' && word[i] <= 'Z'` (and add `case 'A'` back or put it into this condition as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your switch by converting `word[i]` into an `int` to take advantage of the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com). According to the Ascii table the letters 'A' to 'Z' are represented by the number from `65` to `90`. Therefore, because you array of points starts at `0` we need to shift `65` elements to the left from the value that will be return by `(int)word[i]`, namely:

```
int index = (int)word[i] - 'A';
```

In your code:

```
sum = sum + points[index];
```

So the code would look like the following :

```
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
int compute_score(string word){
    int word_length = strlen(word);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < word_length ; i++){
        if (islower(word[i]))
            word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
        int index = (int)word[i] - 'A';
        if ('A' <= word[i] && word[i] <= 'Z') 
            sum += POINTS[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Bear in mind, however, and quoting [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil):

> The character codes used in C implementations do not necessarily have
> all the letters consecutively. ASCII does and is very common, but not
> required by the standard.

Hence, this solution will work if your encoding is ASCI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of strings and define symbols that you want to use for each case:

```
  const int NUM_POINTS = 5;
  const char *strings[NUM_POINTS];

  strings[0] = "ABC";
  strings[1] = "XYZ";
  ...

  for (int p = 0; p < NUM_POINTS; ++p)
  {
      if (strchr(strings[p], word[i]) != NULL)
      {
          sum += POINTS[p];
          break;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your "POINTS" array is meant to be points-per-letter. In other words, the first element is points for an 'A', the second is points for a 'B', etc.

Each character has a numeric ASCII value, and you can use characters in arithmetic. The ASCII values are shown below (borrowed from [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

(This only applies if your encoding is ASCII, which is usually the case except for scenarios like if the data was read from a UTF-16 file or you are compiling for a retro computer that predates ASCII.)

[image]

So you need a way to convert the letter 'A' to the number '0' (the first item in the list is index 0), the letter 'B' to the number '1', etc.

You can do that by simply subtracting a set value from the letter. Notice that a capital 'A' has value 65, 'B' is 66, 'C' is 67, etc.

So simply subtract the value of 'A'.

```c
const int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(const char *word)
{
    int score = 0;

    // iterate over each character in the word.
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        // if this is a capital letter
        if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            // if word[i] is 'A', index is 0. if 'B', then 1. if 'C', then 2. etc.
            int index = word[i] - 'A';
            score += POINTS[index];
        }
        // if this is a lowercase letter
        else if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
        {
            // if word[i] is 'a', index is 0. if 'b', then 1. if 'c', then 2. etc.
            int index = word[i] - 'a';
            score += POINTS[index];
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

Comment: The character codes used in C implementations are not necessarily ASCII. ASCII is very common, but not required by the standard. When supplying an answer that includes requirements that are not part of the C standard, they should be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the `switch` with this `for` loop + `if` condition:

```
char cases[4] = "BCDE";
int notFound = 1;

for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    
    if( word[i] == cases[j] ) {
    
        sum += POINTS[j+2];
        notFound = 0;
        break;
}

if( notFound ) {
    
    sum += POINTS[1];
}
```

If you wanted the cases from `'F'` to `'Z'` to add from `POINTS[6]` to `POINTS[26]`, the algorithm becomes even easier:

```
char cases[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
    
    if( word[i] == cases[j] ) {
    
        sum += POINTS[j+1];
        break;
}
```